How can I make the trench coat stop looking rippled and torn in cloth simulation?
I been messing with the settings trying every combination high and low and still can't seem to make the cloth look less ripped and torn.
I know collision has a lot to do it but I wondered what am I doing wrong here? Cloth simulation seems very tricky so would like to understand what's wrong here? I even double checked if it was my topology.
Blender file here: https://workupload.com/file/5DHFvnUbvJh

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Hello, the coat you're showing has no Cloth simulation, only Collision. Also it has 460,000 vetices, which will be a lot to calculate, lower down the amount of vertices.

I must of forgot to put the cloth simulation on it Also I thought more geometry wouldn't be too bad, but I guess I subdivided way too much. Experimented more after I posted and got some better results going to try to run more test thank you for letting me know this! (I also tried providing more info on this post but was sadly in a rush on time and still can't seem to find out where my screenshots go.)
